# Dialogflow Integration with external/3rd party public API

Tags: api, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, chatbot

I am creating a chatbot within DialogFlow Google framework. I am new to this. I am having trouble with connecting an external/3rd party public API. Just to see how things work, I want to use Meetup API in my Google Assistant. I have created a simple project on Dialogflow called Smart Voice and I would like to integrate the Meetup API to this chatbot.

My approach:

GET data by getJSON (Meetup response payloads are returned in JSON format) and see the data on `console.log` which displays in firebase console (see image below)

[image]

The output should come like this on the console log (image taken from Meetup API Console)

[image]

I tried to do this on inline editor (see code & image below), but I don't know how to do it in the right way.

```js
var url = 'https://api.meetup.com/2/categories?&sign=true&photo-host=public&page=20';
https.get(url, function(res) {
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        var response = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("Got a response: ", response.result);
    });
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got an error: ", e);
});
```

[image]

Then there is this webhook (below is an image in DialogFlow of my webhook), I don't really understand what to put on webhook.

[image]

The overall idea is:

For example, If I ask the chatbot 'Get the upcoming NY Tech Meetups' so it should look up and display the meetups.

I would like to know the steps to approach this matter. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you having a specific problem integrating an API, or having problems getting started? If you can show the code you're currently using, and problems or errors that you're having, we can better help you with your problem.

Comment: Hi @Prisoner, Thank you for replying. I have edited my question and included photos.

Comment: The images are very helpful, however, when sharing things that are text (such as code) on StackOverflow, having the text in the question is **significantly** more useful than having screen shots. People can't cut-and-paste your screen shots to test your code, and search engines can't index your screen shots so people with the same errors won't find your question or, hopefully, the answer you get that solves it. I think we can help you, but it would help us a lot if you could also update your question to include the text of your error messages and code.

Comment: To date (Q1 2020), DialogFlow only allows you to configure one webhook URL per agent, that means your webhook (self-hosted or on inline editor) must be able to manage the intents you specify (_intent > fulfillment > Enable webhook call for this intent_); while we are waiting for a webhook URL per intent –as [SAP Conversational AI](https://cai.tools.sap/) does– I recommend you read about 'Create fulfillment using webhook' on [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/tutorials/build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook)

Comment: [Dialogflow Tutorials: Integrate Your Dialogflow Agent with External APIs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4IPOeFCDxI)